# Modify form's entity based on one of submited fields

Tags: forms, symfony

i have an entity, with relations:

```
deposit:
    - many to one 'vehicleModel'
    - one to many 'tires'
vehicleModel:
    - many to one 'vehicleType'
vehicleType:
    - field 'defaultTireNumber'
```

What i want to achieve, is to create a form for deposit with a select 'vehicleModel' and collection 'tires'. When vehicleModel is selected, then deposit will have tires added (with nuber of $vehicleModel->getType()->getDefaultTiresNumber()), so the form will have also tires subforms (which number will be taken from $vehicleModel relation).
What i have now (not working at all):

```
    $vehicleModelModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Vehicle\Model $vehicleModel, FormEvent $event) {
        $deposit = $event->getData();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $vehicleModel->getType()->getDefaultTiresNumber(); $i++) {
            $deposit->addTire(new Tire());
        }
        $event->setData($deposit);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($vehicleModelModifier) {
            $vehicleModel = $event->getForm()->get('vehicleModel')->getData();
            $vehicleModelModifier($event->getForm(), $vehicleModel, $event);
        }
    );
```

**SOLVED**
The solution was to inject modelRepository and listen to PRE_SUBMIT event, retrieve vehicleModel ID, and get the object from repository:

```
        $vehicleModelModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Vehicle\Model $vehicleModel = null) {
        $deposit = $form->getData();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $vehicleModel->getType()->getDefaultTiresNumber(); $i++) {
            $deposit->addTire(new Tire());
        }

        $form->add('tires', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => TireType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($vehicleModelModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (isset($data['vehicleModel'])) {
                $vehicleModelId = $data['vehicleModel'];
                $vehicleModel = $this->modelRepository->find($vehicleModelId);
                $vehicleModelModifier($event->getForm(), $vehicleModel);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? How it doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is that when i select vehicleModel and press save, the form should be reloaded (with validation error, as expected), but with Tire subforms added (number of tires is depending on selected vehicleModel). Now form reloads with validation error as expected, but tires form is not being populated. I have set a breakpoint invehicleModelModifier function, and it adds tires to deposit entity, but it doesn't change the form

Comment: Are you sure the `POST_SUBMIT` event doesn't happen too late?